# Checking gross errors in Python 3 source using parser module

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I need to check python source for **gross errors** (i.e. to check general correctness of the source) using `parser` module. I thried to use `parser.suite(src)` and `parser.expr(src)`. But these methods always build parse tree.

For example, if I apply to the input random text file instead of python source, I get a tree, which contains `(n, 'Err')`, where `n` - number of the parse element (also I can get `SyntaxError`). But my source also may contains `(n, 'Err')` if it contains some element named `Err`.

So, how I can distinguish trees of incorrect source (incorrect in general with gross errors)?

Comment: So at a bottom line do you want to check whether syntax is correct or not?

Comment: Yes. But I know, that it is impossible to check **all** errors using `parse` module. I need to check only gross errors.

Comment: Why not using a [linter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7925369/3991125) instead?

Comment: I will use pyflaces, pylint and maybe pep8. But it is the next stage of analysing code. In first stage I have to **weed out** the files with gross errors (or files which don't contains python sources at all). This is requirement to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
from sys import argv

try:
    compile(open(argv[1]).read(), argv[1], 'exec', 0, 1)
except SyntaxError as err:
    print('%s:%s:%s: %s' % (err.filename, err.lineno, err.offset, err.msg))
```

This works with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: But the `compile()` function with `'exec'` parameter is the same as `parser.suite()`, isn't it? [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html)

Comment: @VeLKerr Your point being?  The script above doesn't care about the result of the parse.  It just prints a message if it finds an error (and doesn't print anything if the file looks ok).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @lcd047, I solved my problem:

```
import parser, sys


def check_serious_errors(fname):
    return parser.st2tuple(parser.suite(open(fname).read()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        tree = check_serious_errors(sys.argv[1])
    except SyntaxError:
        print("Gross errors was found. Exit")
    else:
        print("File is correct in general. Let's move further!")
        # Further analysis
```